# How does the default controller action work in .NET 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Looking at one of the project templates in .NET 6, I can see this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
```

The `Get` method can be invoked by calling `/weatherforecast`, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't `/weatherforecast/get` be the correct url? The default controller action method should be `Index`. Why does it work?

Comment: Does this article in the documentation answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#http-verb-templates

Comment: If you want /weatherforecast/get then change [Route("[controller]")] to [Route("[controller]/[action]")] on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line no 2 as below to get what you want

```
[ApiController]
//Change this line 
//[Route("[controller]")]
//Like
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you added `[HttpGet]` attribute to the method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#verb6

Answer (score 0):

you're talking about an ApiController, which means it is created to be consumed via an http request.

The `[HttpGet]` attribute specifies that you want to expose this method via HTTP GET.

if you do something line `[HttpGet("my-method")]`  the endpoint would be `/api/<controllername>/my-method`

so if you want the url the be `/weatherforecast/get` you have to specify it as

```
[HttpGet("get")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{}
```

It is very well explained on the [microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#http-verb-templates)